# Como instalar laravel collective en laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel

[image: FatalErrorException Class 'Form' not found]

Muy buenas a todos, he estado tratando de usar laravel collective, pero me he topado con que no hay documentacion para instalar en la version 8 de laravel, alguien me puede decir como puedo instalar.

Tambien he estado intenando inslar laravel/ui sin tener exito.

Espero me puedan ayudar!!! gracias!

Comment: Pueda que me equivoque, pero en esta version no se instala el iu con el auth.

Comment: Estaba instalando admin lte, segun la documentacion, cuando llegue al paso php artisan ui vue --auth, me dio el siguiente mensaje   Command "ui" is not defined. de aca que esoy intentando instalar laravel ui para poder seguir

Comment: Según el historial de [releases](https://github.com/LaravelCollective/html/releases) la versión 6.2.0 es compatible con Laravel 8.

Answer (score 0):

Hola si se puede instalar el ui, solo tienes que seguir los pasos de instalación de la versión laravel 7x. comando por el terminal: composer require laravel/ui; luego ingresas en por el terminal: php artisan ui bootstrap --auth; por ultimo te va a pedir npm install y npm run dev. Y con esto podras instalar el login, register, y reset password de laravel 7 en la version 8.

Answer (score 0):

Lo ideal sería que consultes la página web de laravel collective para saber cuales son los comandos para instalarlos. Ya que con el tiempo es probable que los comandos estén actualizados.
En la web de https://laravelcollective.com/docs/6.x/html se precisa usar el comando

```
composer require laravelcollective/html
```

Answer (score 0):

`Laravel UI` no necesita nada de eso

https://github.com/laravel/ui

`Laravel Collection` ya esta obsoleto, use solo `HTML 5`

pero si aun así quieres usarlo, puedes intentar con

https://laravelcollective.com/docs/6.x/html